# How to do literature review

Tags: academic-writing, research

We often hear that literature review (*LR*) is not mere summarizing the writings of other, rather it is scrutinizing finding the material relevant to one's own research and the gaps to be filled.

Can anyone give me specific guidelines on *LR* in terms of examples and resources? Googling will give many listings but I would like to know it from your own experience either as a learner or as a teacher. You may kindly provide one specific tip/resource or example.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Here's a very good article on the subject: [_Writing a Literature Review_](http://www.canberra.edu.au/studyskills/writing/literature), from Canberra's Academic Skills Centre. I also found [this](http://www.lc.unsw.edu.au/onlib/litrev.html) and [this](http://voices.yahoo.com/how-write-academic-literature-review-2612200.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding, from what I have been told in my thesis work, is that the literature review should demonstrate that you have read everything that is critical to your work, understood it, and can explain why it is relevant.

More practically, this means that you need to identify the core areas of your subject that relate to your thesis topic. They within these areas, identify the most critical texts, and read them. Then write sections that explore the *topic*, drawing heavily from the *books* with quotes. Make sure that you are arguing for What this area involves into Why this is relevant.

In my case, for HCI, I talk a little about introducing new technology, because this is a critical part of HCI design, and I refer to Zuboff and Bannon, referened below. These are the two key authors in the specific area focus that I need to address, and I quote them liberally talking around the focus of the topic that I require.

If your writing is just a litereature review, then it probably needs more detail, more personal exploration of the topic in more depth. But the principles are the same - read the most important literature on the specific topic, and demonstrate that you understand it.

Zuboff, S (1988) In the age of the smart machine – the future of work and power, Oxford: Heinemann Professional Publishing

Bannon, L (1991) From Human Factors to Human Actors. In Greenbaum, J and Kyng, M (Eds.)(1991) Design at work: Cooperative Design of Computer Systems. Hillsdale: Lawrence Erlbaum Associates pp. 25-44

Bannon, L (2011) Reimagining HCI: Towards a more Human-Centred Perspective. Interactions. New York: ACM, pp50-57

Answer (score 0):

6 types of literature review i came across from advices of experts:

Type 1: Framework Based Review
Paul, J., & Rosado-Serrano, A. (2019). Gradual Internationalization vs BornGlobal/International new venture models: A review and research agenda. International Marketing Review. (TCCM Framework)
https://www.emerald.com/insight/content/doi/10.1108/IMR-10-2018-0280/full/html

Type 2: Review of a Theory in a Specific Field
Gilal et.al (2018). The role of self-determination theory in marketing science: An integrative review and agenda for research. European Management Journal.
https://doi.org/10.1016/j.emj.2018.10.004

Type 3: Theme-Based Systematic Literature Reviews with Directions for Future Research
Paul, J., Parthasarathy, S., & Gupta, P. (2017). Exporting challenges of SMEs: A review and future research agenda. Journal of world business, 52(3), 327-342
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1090951617300366
Kahiya, E. T. (2018). Five decades of research on export barriers: Review and future directions. International Business Review
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0969593117303141

Type 4: Review Aiming for Theory/ Theoretical Model/Framework Development
(These are types of the Review articles published in Academy of Management Review & Academy of Marketing Science Review)
Paul, J. (2019), Marketing in emerging markets: a review, theoretical synthesis and extension. International Journal of Emerging Markets
https://doi.org/10.1108/IJOEM-04-2017-0130

Type 5: Structured Review Focusing on Methods, Constructs, Context and Theories
Paul, J., & Singh, G. (2017). The 45 years of foreign direct investment research: Approaches, advances and analytical areas. The World Economy, 40(11), 2512-2527
https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/twec.12502

Type 6: Bibliometric Analysis Review
Randhawa, K., Wilden, R., & Hohberger, J. (2016). A bibliometric review of open innovation: Setting a research agenda. Journal of Product Innovation Management, 33(6), 750-772
https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/jpim.12312

Lastly, like to share two published reviews that i was part of:
Rahman, S. M., Carlson, J., & Chowdhury, N. H. (2022). SafeCX: a framework for safe customer experience in omnichannel retailing. Journal of Services Marketing.
https://www.emerald.com/insight/content/doi/10.1108/JSM-04-2021-0114/full/html
And,
Chowdhury, N. H., Adam, M. T., & Skinner, G. (2019). The impact of time pressure on cybersecurity behaviour: a systematic literature review. Behaviour & Information Technology, 38(12), 1290-1308.